# Increase tx power in WPEA-121N Wifi Card

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, linux-device-driver

I trying to increase tx-power on WPEA-121N Wifi Card (Atheros AR9382 Chip) but i just cant set it over 18 dBm.
Inside datasheet specification i can see that power consumption for continue TX is 600mA so the output power should be around 1.98W (3,3V*0.6A) wchich is around 33 dBm.
I change regulatory.bin file to allow setting tx power over 30 dBm on every frequency. But neither commands:

```
iw dev wlp1s0 set txpower fixed 2500
```

or

```
iwconfig wlp1s0 txpower 25dBm
```

cant change txpower over 18 dBm.

I have modified linux modules using patches from: [ath9k: Differentiate between max combined and per chain power](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10861389/) and [ath9k-3.12.8-1-maxpower.patch](https://github.com/lucatib/bdj_wap/blob/master/test/ath9k-3.12.8-1-maxpower.patch) but noone of this is working.

Inside /drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/hw.h there is defined variable:

```
#define MAX_RATE_POWER              63
```

and 63 mW indicate that this is max power i can set (18dBm) but changing this (to 254) also do nothing.

ath9k running as a modules so i guess i dont need to recompile whole kernel but just to remake modules and copy&replace them inside /lib//modules/*kernelNumber*/kernel/drivers/.....

Is there any way to override max power to incresae it over 30 dBm?

Any suggestion?